# Can anyone explain the following Scala code?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, bubble-sort

I have to describe BubbleSort in Scala and I tested it with this code. But I don't know exactly what each of the functions does.

```
object BubbleSort {
  def sort(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = list match {
    case List() => List()
    case head :: tail => compute(head, sort(tail))
  }

  def compute(data: Int, dataSet: List[Int]): List[Int] = dataSet match {
    case List() => List(data)
    case head :: tail => if (data <= head) data :: dataSet else head :: compute(data, tail)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val list = List(3, 12, 43, 23, 7, 1, 2, 0)
    println(sort(list))
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain it to me?

Comment: This is insertion sort, not bubble sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look how your functions work starting from the last element

```
sort(List()) // List()
compute(0, List()) // List(0)
sort(List(0))      // List(0)
compute(2, List(0)) // List(0, 2)
sort(List(2, 0))    // List(0, 2)
compute(1, List(0, 2)) // List(0, 1, 2)
sort(List(1, 0, 2))    // List(0, 1, 2)
compute(7, List(0, 1, 2)) // List(0, 1, 2, 7)
sort(List(7, 0, 1, 2))    // List(0, 1, 2, 7)
compute(23, List(0, 1, 2, 7)) // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23)
sort(List(23, 0, 1, 2, 7))    // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23)
compute(43, List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23)) // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23, 43)
sort(List(43, 0, 1, 2, 7, 23))    // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23, 43)
compute(12, List(0, 1, 2, 7, 23, 43)) // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 23, 43)
sort(List(12, 0, 1, 2, 7, 23, 43))    // List(0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 23, 43)
compute(3, List(0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 23, 43)) // List(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 12, 23, 43)
sort(List(3, 0, 1, 2, 7, 12, 23, 43))    // List(0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 12, 23, 43)
```

`compute` pushes the element ("bubble") till proper place.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the [classic definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) of a Bubble Sort involves swapping adjacent elements if they are out of order. There's no swapping going on here so it doesn't really look like a true Bubble Sort.

The `compute()` method might, more properly, be called `insert()` because that's what it does. It inserts a `data` element into an already-sorted `dataSet`. The trivial case is when the `data` element belongs at the head of (or only element in) the `dataSet`. If that's not the case then it puts the head of the current `dataSet` aside (on the call-stack) and recurses until `data` **can** be put at the head, then the call-stack is unwound, rebuilding the `dataSet` with the latest `data` element in place.

The `sort()` method is a bit simpler. It just pulls the head off of the current `list` and places it on the call-stack until `list` is empty, and thus, sorted. Then it unwinds, passing each element to `compute()` along with the sorted result returned from the previous call.